# How to get the size of a list returned by column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, for-loop, pyspark, list-comprehension

| name | contact | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "max" | [{"email": "watson@commerce.gov", "phone": "650-333-3456"}, {"email": "emily@gmail.com", "phone": "238-111-7689"}] | {"city": "Baltimore", "state": "MD"} |
| "kyle" | [{"email": "johnsmith@yahoo.com", "phone": "425-231-8754"}] | {"city": "Barton", "state": "TN"} |

I am working with a dataframe in Pyspark that has a few columns including the two mentioned above. I need to create columns dynamically based on the contact fields.

When I use the "." operator on `contact` as `contact.email` I get a list of emails. I need to create separate column for each of the emails.
`contact.email0`, `contact.email1`, etc.

I found this code online, which partially does what I want, but I don't completely understand it.

```
employee_data.select(
    'name', *[col('contact.email')[i].alias(f'contact.email{i}') for i in range(2)]).show(truncate=False)
```

The range is static in this case, but my range could be dynamic. How can I get the size of list to loop through it? I tried `size(col('contact.email'))` or `len(col('contact.email'))` but got an error saying the `col('column name')` object is not iterable.

Desired output something like -

| name | contact.email0 | contact.email1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| max | watson@commerce.gov | emily@gmail.com |
| kyle | johnsmith@yahoo.com | null |

Comment: Please add expected output

Comment: Sorry about that, updated with desired output

Answer (score 1):

You can get desired output by using `pivot` function,

```
# convert contact struct to array of emails by using transform function
# explode the array 
# perform pivot
 df.select("name", posexplode_outer(expr("transform(contact, c-> c.email)"))) \
    .withColumn("email", concat(lit("contact.email"), col("pos"))) \
    .groupBy("name").pivot("email").agg(first("col")) \
    .show(truncate=False)

+----+-------------------+---------------+
|name|contact.email0     |contact.email1 |
+----+-------------------+---------------+
|kyle|johnsmith@yahoo.com|null           |
|max |watson@commerce.gov|emily@gmail.com|
+----+-------------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand what the solution you found does, we can print the expression in a shell:

```
>>> [F.col('contact.email')[i].alias(f'contact.email{i}') for i in range(2)]
[Column<'contact.email[0] AS `contact.email0`'>, Column<'contact.email[1] AS `contact.email1`'>]
```

Basically, it creates two columns, one for the first element of the array `contact.email` and one for the second element. That's all there is to it.

**SOLUTION 1**

Keep this solution. But you need to find the max size of your array first:

```py
max_size = df.select(F.max(F.size("contact"))).first()[0]
df.select('name',
    *[F.col('contact')[i]['email'].alias(f'contact.email{i}') for i in range(max_size)])\
  .show(truncate=False)
```

**SOLUTION 2**

Use `posexplode` to generate one row per element of the array + a pos column containing the index of the email in the array. Then use a pivot to create the columns you want.

```py
df.select('name', F.posexplode('contact.email').alias('pos', 'email'))\
  .withColumn('pos', F.concat(F.lit('contact.email'), 'pos'))\
  .groupBy('name')\
  .pivot('pos')\
  .agg(F.first('email'))\
  .show()
```

Both solutions yield:

```
+----+-------------------+---------------+
|name|contact.email0     |contact.email1 |
+----+-------------------+---------------+
|max |watson@commerce.gov|emily@gmail.com|
|kyle|johnsmith@yahoo.com|null           |
+----+-------------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `size` or `array_length` functions to get the length of the list in the `contact` column, and then use that in the `range` function to dynamically create columns for each email. Here's an example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import size, array_length

contact_size = size(col('contact'))

employee_data.select(
    'name', *[col('contact')[i]['email'].alias(f'contact.email{i}') for i in range(contact_size)]).show(truncate=False)
```

Or, using `array_length`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import size, array_length

contact_size = array_length(col('contact'))

employee_data.select(
    'name', *[col('contact')[i]['email'].alias(f'contact.email{i}') for i in range(contact_size)]).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: `array_length` is not a method in `pyspark.sql.functions` in the latest version of pyspark. Please edit your answer or provide documentation showing its existence.